# How can I resolve the Java error I'm getting

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java programming. I installed Jedit a while ago, then Jedit asked me to install java application so I did that. When I tried compiling my first code it told me I had PATH issues so I downloaded "JDK 12.0.1", and I resolved the PATH issues. When I tried running the code it self it kept giving me this error

Can anyone help me out.

I've searched online but nothing seems to be working

This is the error message I'm getting

```
>   "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Example1 has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file 
versions up to 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
> Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Error: A
> JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" Process java exited with code 1"
```

Comment: How are you running the code? This happens when you compile the code with one jre version and tries to execute with another one.

Comment: so, you compiled it with Java 12... what version of Java are you running it with? It pretty much boils down to this: You send a tablet with an English pdf back to medieval England assuming they can read it because, "it's English, right?" That's not how it works. The java version you're running your code with doesn't have the functionality of Java 12, so it can't interpret your .class files

Comment: Use a free IDE like netbeans to learn java with. It shields you from niggly problems like this

Comment: @Rick No, it doesn't. If your ide is configured with JDK x and in your environment properties you have an older Java, same problem. IDE's, especially professional ones like NetBeans should not be used by those just starting. They should be used by those with years of experience, to fasten up things, not by those that just want to skip on "learning the details"

Comment: Thanks....
So how do i make my java version the same with Java 12?

Comment: How are you compiling your class ? If with command line, share it, if with an IDE, share the configuration of it. Same questions about how you run your code ?

Comment: I use "javac.class" on the Jedit IDE to compile.   then i use "java class" to run